# Search using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have one Textbox, Button and Gridview; I want to Search in multiple columns.
It works but of course in the last case only and ignores the above, so i need something when any case has value exist in my database will filter it. What should i do to make it possible?
This my code.

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Item item = new Item();

    //Search by item_name
    using (SupermarketEntities1 DB = new SupermarketEntities1())
    {
        item.item_name = txt_search.Text;

        itemGridView.DataSource = DB.Items.Where(x => x.item_name .Contains( item.item_name))
            .Select(x =>new {
                    x.item_id,
                    x.item_name,
                    x.item_unit,
                    x.Department.depart_name,
                    x.prod_date,
                    x.exp_date,
                    x.sale_price,
                    x.purchase_price,
                }).ToList();
        itemGridView.DataBind();
    }

    //Search by item_unit
    using (SupermarketEntities1 DB = new SupermarketEntities1())
    {
        item.item_unit = txt_search.Text;

        itemGridView.DataSource = DB.Items.Where(x => x.item_unit.Contains(item.item_unit))
            .Select(x => new {
                x.item_id,
                x.item_name,
                x.item_unit,
                x.Department.depart_name,
                x.prod_date,
                x.exp_date,
                x.sale_price,
                x.purchase_price, 
            }).ToList();
        itemGridView.DataBind();
    }

    //Search by sale_price
    using (SupermarketEntities1 DB = new SupermarketEntities1())
    {
        item.sale_price = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_search.Text);

        itemGridView.DataSource = DB.Items.Where(x => x.sale_price == item.sale_price)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.item_id,
                x.item_name,
                x.item_unit,
                x.Department.depart_name,
                x.prod_date,
                x.exp_date,
                x.sale_price,
                x.purchase_price                  
            }).ToList();
        itemGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you're looking for is the logical *or* operator: `||`

In your `.Where()` clause, you would check if any of the values match.  Something like this:

```
DB.Items.Where(x =>
    x.item_name.Contains(item.item_name) ||
    x.item_unit.Contains(item.item_unit) ||
    x.sale_price == item.sale_price)
```

So build your `item` object however you need to, then have a *single* LINQ query with all of the comparisons in a *single* `.Where()` clause, and set the results of that query to your data source.

Comment: it works, But the same problem if  x.sale_price == item.sale_price) case exist So i hashed it and it works fine